# Get the comment author ID by the comment ID

Tags: author, id

I need to get the comment author ID by the comment ID.

**Example**

```
functionName($commentID){
   return $authorID; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use it: `<?php get_comment( $id, $output ); ?>`

### Return

```
comment_ID 
(integer) The comment ID
comment_post_ID 
(integer) The post ID of the associated post
comment_author 
(string) The comment author's name
comment_author_email 
(string) The comment author's email
comment_author_url 
(string) The comment author's webpage
comment_author_IP 
(string) The comment author's IP
comment_date 
(string) The datetime of the comment (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
comment_date_gmt 
(string) The GMT datetime of the comment (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
comment_content 
(string) The comment's contents
comment_karma 
(integer) The comment's karma
comment_approved 
(string) The comment approbation (0, 1 or 'spam')
comment_agent 
(string) The comment's agent (browser, Operating System, etc.)
comment_type 
(string) The comment's type if meaningfull (pingback|trackback), and empty for normal comments
comment_parent 
(string) The parent comment's ID
user_id 
(integer) The comment author's ID if he is registered (0 otherwise)
```

### Final Code

```
$comment_id = $commentID; //$commentID your var

$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

$comment_author_id = $comment -> user_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`get_comment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) to return information about the comment like `comment_author_email`.

You can then try to get a user by email using [`get_user_by`('email', $comment_author_email)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/).

Once you have the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) you should be able to access the `ID` of that user.

*All of this assumes, the comment author's email is used as the user's registration email.*

Comment: get_comment returns user_id
You don't need to use the comment_author_email to get the user_id of the comment. If the user wasn't logged in, then it will be 0.